# How can I get notified of ProcessBean events for a producer method returning a type X?

Tags: java, generics, cdi, type-resolution

A (valid) [CDI producer method](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#producer_method) like this:

```
@Produces public Integer fortyTwo() {  return Integer.valueOf(42); }
```

…is *not* observed by a (valid) portable extension's [container lifecycle event observer method](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#init_events) that looks like this:

```
private final void processBean(@Observes final ProcessBean<Integer> event) { /* ?! */ }
```

...or this:

```
private final void processBean(@Observes final ProcessBean<? extends Number> event) { /* ?! */ }
```

...or this (not surprisingly):

```
private final void processBean(@Observes final ProcessBean<Object> event) { /* obviously */ }
```

...but *is* observed by one that looks like this:

```
private final void processBean(@Observes final ProcessBean<?> event) { /*...*/ }
```

…and the `toString()` output of `event.getBean().getTypes()` at that point is:

```
[class java.lang.Number, class java.lang.Integer, interface java.io.Serializable, class java.lang.Object, java.lang.Comparable<java.lang.Integer>]
```

The [specification says](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#process_bean) that "The event object type in the package `javax.enterprise.inject.spi` depends upon what kind of bean was discovered".  It says in particular that "[f]or a producer method with method return type `T` of a bean with bean class `X`, the container must raise an event of type `ProcessProducerMethod<T, X>`."  Then it lists some other concrete event types which seemingly should cover all bases.

Nevertheless, there is still this `ProcessBean` interface, which is `public` (they could have made it an implementation detail of the concrete events detailed by the specification, and hence "off-limits"), so it would seem it was intended that this should be observable directly.  Unfortunately, as noted, the only way I've found to write a container lifecycle event observer method that *does* observe `ProcessBean` is to observe `ProcessBean<?>` and none other.

I find this all very surprising.  Is this pilot error or a bug in Weld (the CDI implementation I'm using)?  What should I do if I want to be notified of every bean of a given type, regardless of whether it's a managed bean, session bean, synthetic bean, producer method or producer field?

Comment: A very wild guess, as I have nothing to test right now: `private final <T, X extends Operation<T>> void processBean(@Observes final ProcessBean<X> event)`?

Comment: Thanks; it's a good idea, but no luck.  Interestingly I have boiled it down further.  A producer method that returns `Integer` will not be reported to a `ProcessBean<Integer>` observer method, but will be reported to a `ProcessBean<?>` observer method.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: I've filed https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WELD-2461 because after digging into things with the debugger it looks like at least in this one case (maybe others, but not straightforward obvious ones) the type parameters supplied to Weld's implementation of `ProcessProducerMethod` get reversed.  The net effect is that the `ProcessBean` implementation event that gets fired gets reported as having the _host bean_ type, not the actual _producer method bean_ type.